# Bootstrap typeahead suggestion links with jquery click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm struggling for 3-4 hours with `Bootstrap's typeahead` that I downloaded from `https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/`
I'm trying to add a click function with typeahead's suggestion to change page with javascript's `window.location.href`.
My typeahaed works well with json values

```
// Typeahead
$("#search-product").typeahead({
    ajax: {
        url: "_inc/search-json.php?product=",
        timeout: 500,
        displayField: "product_name",
        triggerLength: 3,
        method: "get",
        preDispatch: function (query) {
            return {
                search: query
            }
        },
    }
});
```

In suggestion `ul` suggestions coming with 2 values; 1)Product Name, 2) Product Id. Sample html structure;

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="166" class=""><a href="#"><strong>TK03</strong>0</a></li>
    <li data-value="167"><a href="#"><strong>TK03</strong>1</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I try to add click function to `li`'s redirect user to product detail page with `jquery` code;

```
var productId = $('.typeahead li').data("value");
$(".typeahead").on( "click", "li", function() {
    window.location.href = "/product-details.php?i=" + productId;
});
```

But it's always redirecting to: `product-details.php?i=undefined`
What is wrong with my code, what am I missing?

Comment: `var productId = $(this).data("value");` Have you tried this inside your `click` callback

Comment: `var productId = $('.typeahead li').data("value");` outside your click handler dosen't make any sense to me

Comment: @SandeepNayak it worked. Thank you. Change your comment to answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var productId = $('.typeahead li').data("value"); // Doesnt make any sense outside the click callback. Instead write it within the callback like shown below.
```

You need to fetch the product Id it like this inside your `click` callback:

```
$(".typeahead").on( "click", "li", function() {
   var productId = $(this).data("value");  // $(this) refers to the clicked li
   window.location.href = "/product-details.php?i=" + productId;
});
```