# get value from jquery type ahead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have implemented live search with jquery **typeahead** library, it is working fine for the case of data being received from database i have  the issue on front end

right now the **typeahead** is working fine for displaying data what i want to do is add url in the href attribute of the `li's`being generated from the dropdown but i havent still been able to even attach an `onclick` method with the `li's` here's my code so far.

**HTML**

```
  <input autocomplete="off" id="type" placeholder="Search for product / category"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#type').typeahead({
            source: function (query, result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>ajax_search/search2",
                    data: 'query=' + query,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        result($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**PHP CI Model Function**

```
public function search($query){
        $keyword = strval($query);
        $search_param = "{$keyword}%";
        $conn =new mysqli($this->db->hostname, $this->db->username, $this->db->password , $this->db->database);
        $countryResult[]=array();
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE ?");
        $sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $countryResult[] = $row["name"];
            }
            echo json_encode($countryResult);
        }
    }
```

this is the html structure that is being generated when **typeahead** is called

this is what i have tried so far!

```
$(".typeahead").on( "click", "li", function() {
            alert("1");
        });

        $(".typeahead .dropdown-item").delegate("click", function(){
            alert("12");
        });

        $(".typeahead .dropdown-item").on("click", function(){
            alert("123");
        });
```

i copied one  of the code from this thread [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034373/bootstrap-typeahead-suggestion-links-with-jquery-click-not-working) but it is still not working for my case i have not  idea why it is not working any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element you are attaching the click event to will have been added to the DOM dynamically by typehead, you'll want to do so like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.typeahead .dropdown-item', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: one one theoretical question live/delegate method does exactly the same thing  why it didnt worked?

Comment: live and delegate have been deprecated.